How to build a Docker image that installs Solana on Mac?
I'm using a Macbook trying to run this DockerFile from Solana Playground with docker compose up.
################# BASE RUST INSTALLATION TO USE IN OTHER STEPS #################
FROM ubuntu:22.04 as rust

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"

ENV HOME="/root"

# Install build deps
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get upgrade -qq && apt-get install -qq \
    build-essential curl pkg-config libssl-dev libudev-dev

# Install Rust
RUN sh -c "$(curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs)" -- -y
ENV PATH="${HOME}/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

############################## BUILD SERVER BINARY #############################
FROM rust as build

WORKDIR /build
COPY Cargo.* .
COPY src src
RUN cargo build --release

################################# START SERVER #################################
FROM rust

ARG SOLANA_VERSION="1.17.0"

# Install Solana
RUN sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v${SOLANA_VERSION}/install)"
ENV PATH="${HOME}/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:${PATH}"

# Set the workdir
WORKDIR /home/pg

# Copy programs dir and build the default program
COPY programs programs
RUN cargo-build-sbf --manifest-path programs/Cargo.toml

# Start server
COPY --from=build /build/target/release/solpg-server .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./solpg-server"]

Which returns this error:
command failed: downloader https://release.solana.com/v1.17.0/solana-install-init-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu /tmp/tmp.8uZgeReXh2/solana-install-init

 => ERROR [server stage-2 1/5] RUN sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.17.0/install)"                1.1s
 => [server build 2/4] COPY Cargo.* .                                                                              0.0s
 => [server build 3/4] COPY src src                                                                                0.0s
 => CANCELED [server build 4/4] RUN cargo build --release                                                          1.0s
------
 > [server stage-2 1/5] RUN sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.17.0/install)":
0.537 downloading v1.17.0 installer
0.706 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
0.707 solana-install-init: command failed: downloader https://release.solana.com/v1.17.0/solana-install-init-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu /tmp/tmp.8uZgeReXh2/solana-install-init
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c sh -c \"$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v${SOLANA_VERSION}/install)\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Some freeCodeCamp solana course users also seem to encounter this error.
Found this related question
403 Error when downloading Solana install tool, so I tried building from source as recommended.
But then I get an error from cargo-build-sbf about platform tools.
Failed to install platform-tools: HTTP status client error (404 Not Found) for url (https://github.com/anza-xyz/platform-tools/releases/download/v1.41/platform-tools-linux-aarch64.tar.bz2)

 > [server stage-3 4/5] RUN cargo-build-sbf --manifest-path programs/Cargo.toml:
6.822 [2024-06-08T04:12:38.827830924Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to install platform-tools: HTTP status client error (404 Not Found) for url (https://github.com/anza-xyz/platform-tools/releases/download/v1.41/platform-tools-linux-aarch64.tar.bz2)
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cargo-build-sbf --manifest-path programs/Cargo.toml" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Have not figured out how to build the platform tools. Seems like others have also encountered this issue
There seems to be an answer from this question cargo build-bpf in a sandbox environment, but I'm not sure how to implement.
Lastly I found this docker image from solanalabs. But when trying to use it I get the follow error, which seems to generally be related to using Anchor on windows.
Failed to obtain package metadata: `cargo metadata` exited with an error:

=> ERROR [server stage-3 6/6] RUN cargo-build-sbf --manifest-path programs/Cargo.toml                             0.1s
------
 > [server stage-3 6/6] RUN cargo-build-sbf --manifest-path programs/Cargo.toml:
0.099 [2024-06-08T15:25:51.817970379Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to obtain package metadata: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: 
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cargo-build-sbf --manifest-path programs/Cargo.toml" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Does anyone know how to resolve these errors or has a dockerfile that works with Mac?

Still using the Solana Playground server DockerFile as example.
Instead of running:
docker compose up

First run:
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t testing:v0 --load .

This builds and saves the docker image. Change testing:v0 to whatever you'd like.

Then run:
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -d -p 8080:8080 testing:v0

This starts a container using the image.

